# React. PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.number) - how it work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

friends! I figure out why `PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.number)` does not apply to prop `ar` ? I want to do a type checking before release, but it does not work.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import './index.css';

class Greeting extends React.Component {
  render() {

    const ar = {
      a: 123,
      b: '123'
    }

    return (
      <div>Hello, {ar.a}!</div>
    );
  }
}

Greeting.propTypes = {
  ar: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.number)
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Greeting />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: What you're using is supposed to apply to an object which has only numbers stored. Like `{ x: 1.2, y: 3.4 }`. Plus, your only prop for `Greeting` is `name`, which is a `String`. See https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html (I assume you have looked at that page, given your code. However you don't seem to understand what a `prop` is)

Comment: @ChrisG yes, I know this instruction. And in my case `PropTypes` must catch an error, because the `prop name` come to us like a string, not a number. But it's not happen...

Comment: `ar` IS NOT A `prop`. To be clear, the props are checked when the Component is mounted. The render method does not care about propTypes. `ar` is a local `const`, not a `prop`. Your Greeting component has no props currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With prop types you check the props that pass to your component. ar is not a prop but an object you define in it.

Check this [PropTypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)

You should check the name which is a prop:

```
Greeting.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.number
};
```

Check this to clear out what props is [Components and Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

Try this if your objective is to check ar:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import './index.css';

class Greeting extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>Hello, {this.props.ar.a}!</div>
    );
  }
}

Greeting.propTypes = {
  ar: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.number)
};

const ar = {
  a: 123,
  b: '123'
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Greeting ar={ar}/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Not a useful answer for me. (
I need an `objectOf` checking, not a directly to a `props`. I have change my description to make it more clearly...

Comment: With propTypes you check the props you pass to your component. The only prop you pass is name: <Greeting name={'Mike'} />

Comment: check my edit, but you do not understand what a prop is, find that out first

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import './index.css';

class Greeting extends Component {
  render() {

    return (
      <div>Hello, {ar.a}!</div>
    );
  }
}

Greeting.propTypes = {
    ar: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.shape({
        a: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        b: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    }).isRequired
};

const ar = {
    a: 123,
    b: '123'
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <Greeting ar={ar} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Well, I was facing the same problem while resolving an eslint error for props. It won't simply accept an object as my prop type, so I had to define the actual shape I was expecting there.

Also, in this example, you should pass ar as a prop to  component and define its shape.